# Update a column sequentially based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm on oracle 11g and I am stuck on this problem.

My table structure is as below

```
 
╔═══════╦══════╦════════╗
║ tm_id ║ flag ║ countr ║
╠═══════╬══════╬════════╣
║ 1     ║ 0    ║ null   ║
║ 2     ║ 0    ║ null   ║
║ 3     ║ 1    ║ null   ║
║ 4     ║ 0    ║ null   ║
╚═══════╩══════╩════════╝
```

I want to update all values of the column countr with a sequential value as below

```
 
╔═══════╦══════╦════════╗
║ tm_id ║ flag ║ countr ║
╠═══════╬══════╬════════╣
║ 1     ║ 0    ║ 1      ║
║ 2     ║ 0    ║ 2      ║
║ 3     ║ 1    ║ 2      ║
║ 4     ║ 0    ║ 3      ║
╚═══════╩══════╩════════╝
```

So basically the value for countr should only increase if the flag is 0. If it is 1 then it shouldn't increase  (or it should have the previous value)

I tried the following update statement

```
UPDATE calendar 
SET countr = case when flag = 0 then  tm_id  else  countr-1 end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b2beb1/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( tm_id, flag, countr ) AS
          SELECT 1,0, CAST( NULL AS NUMBER ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,0, CAST( NULL AS NUMBER ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1, CAST( NULL AS NUMBER ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,0, CAST( NULL AS NUMBER ) FROM DUAL
/

UPDATE test t
SET countr = ( SELECT total
               FROM   (
                        SELECT tm_id,
                               SUM( 1 - FLAG ) OVER ( ORDER BY tm_id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS total
                        FROM   test
                      ) x
               WHERE  t.tm_id = x.tm_id
             )
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b2beb1/1/0)**:

```
| TM_ID | FLAG | COUNTR |
|-------|------|--------|
|     1 |    0 |      1 |
|     2 |    0 |      2 |
|     3 |    1 |      2 |
|     4 |    0 |      3 |
```

**Edit - Explanation**

The use of `SUM` here is as an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) rather than, as typically used, an aggregate function.

```
SUM( 1 - FLAG ) OVER ( ORDER BY tm_id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
```

From (almost) right to left:

- `ORDER BY tm_id`- order the rows by ascending `tm_id`
- Then for each row:

  - Consider all the `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` (i.e. only the rows starting from the earliest `tm_id` to the current row)
  - For those rows find the `SUM( 1 - FLAG )` (i.e. increment the counter when the flag is zero and not when it is one).

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly...I tried googling on the things you used but can you give me some context here? I have trouble putting them together and make sense of what you have written.

Comment: @user1561770 - Explanation of the `SUM` analytic function added.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a subquery in the `update`:

```
update calendar t
    set countr = (select count(*)
                  from calendar t2
                  where t2.tm_id <= t.tm_id and t2.flag = 0
                 );
```

If your table is large, you might find that `merge` is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should use cursor.
Get all rows from table.
Update one by one row in loop bases on case condition.
Store countr value in one declare variable at last of the loop.
Use this variable on next loop round if flag = 1.